# NetworkCredential UseDefaultCredentials not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

We wrote a code long back to call a service with domain credentials. Now domains are changed and planning to use default Windows Account

So I am trying to reset Network credentials for a asmx webservice via config.
I created a SoapExtentsion class and trying to override there even it executes the line. But it never gets applied and always the below existing code win

**Actual Code**

```
EmployeeService prxy = new EmployeeService();
prxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyAccount", "pwd", "MyDomain");
 //prxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;// It works but we dont want code change
prxy.GetEmployee(empId);
```

**New Code / Config Change only**

Planning to inject via additional dll and config changes. So the code change in original above code is not required/prohibited now

```
public class WindowsDefCredSoapExtn : SoapExtension
{
    public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {

      if (message is SoapClientMessage)
          {
          if (message.Stage == SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize)
              {                             
              ((SoapClientMessage)message).Client.Credentials=null;
              (((SoapClientMessage)message)).Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

              }
          }                

        }

    }
}


 <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="MyAssembly.WindowsDefCredSoapExtn, MyAssembly" priority="1" group="Low"/>
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

Any one know how to dynamically change the Network Credentials used for a ASMX service via config?

**UPDATE:**

While debug, I could see the network credentials are reset. But somehow it sends to server when invoking the request.

```
EmployeeService prxy = new EmployeeService();
prxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyAccount", "pwd", "MyDomain");
 //while debug, prxy.UseDefaultCredentials= false here
//My soap extension gets executed and resets credentials.
prxy.GetEmployee(empId);
 //while debug, prxy.UseDefaultCredentials= true here
 //while debug prxy.Credentials are null here.
```

**Output Window:**

See the last line AcquireCredentialsHandle passes `authdata`. The credentials which set in `prxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyAccount", "pwd", "MyDomain")` being used even though my service extension reset.

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] WebRequest::Create(http://employee-service/empService.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] HttpWebRequest#39256744::HttpWebRequest(http://employee-service/empService.asmx#173042156)
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting HttpWebRequest#39256744::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#39256744
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] HttpWebRequest#39256744::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Associating HttpWebRequest#39256744 with ServicePoint#19085264
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Associating Connection#65246235 with HttpWebRequest#39256744
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665::Socket(InterNetwork#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting Socket#27993665::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665::Connect(45:80#763949146)
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665 - Created connection from 10.234.80.99:48954 to 10.242.137.45:80
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] HttpWebRequest#39256744 - Request: POST /empService.asmx HTTP/1.1

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665::Send()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Data from Socket#27993665::Send
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] <<POST /empService.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.2034)

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting Socket#27993665::Send()     -> 512#512
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] ConnectStream#50996063 - Sending headers
{
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.2034)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo3GOBVodvqZLgUWyCSNWI5kAAAAAzHBQpKvNJ0SvKGwy+a3tGerbsJdijWdHqs2PJipnfqYACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://employee-service/GetProperties"
Host: employee-service
Content-Length: 507
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Data from Socket#27993665::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] <<HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 16:11:15 GMT

>>
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting Socket#27993665::Receive()  -> 109#109
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Connection#65246235 - Received status line: Version=1.1, StatusCode=401, StatusDescription=Unauthorized.
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Connection#65246235 - Received headers
{
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 16:11:15 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] ConnectStream#7794715::ConnectStream(Buffered 0 bytes.)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Socket#27993665::MultipleSend()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [11584] Exiting Socket#27993665::MultipleSend() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [11584] Data from ConnectStream#50996063::ResubmitWrite

System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Associating HttpWebRequest#39256744 with ConnectStream#7794715
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Associating HttpWebRequest#39256744 with HttpWebResponse#29471296
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     DPA
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     Digest
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584]     MSN
System.Net Information: 0 : [11584] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package  = NTLM, intent   = Outbound, authdata = MyDomain\MyAccount)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just did a code change for tesing and below is difference in the socket communication

```
AcquireDefaultCredential(package = NTLM, intent  = Outbound)
```

Vs

```
AcquireCredentialsHandle(package  = NTLM, intent   = Outbound, authdata = MyDomain\MyAccount)
```

Comment: If I recall, code config always wins over config files, by design in .NET framework. Config is loaded first, and when code runs, it will overwrite the setting.

Comment: My code injected via config runs again and reset the value. But somehow it is sending the credentials set already.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then I think you need to add keys for your Account, User Name and Password under appSettings in the config file.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="YourDomain" value="yourAccount"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="yourAccount"/>
    <add key="Password" value="yourAccount"/>
</appSettings>
```

After that in your code,

```
EmployeeService prxy = new EmployeeService();
prxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourDomain"].ToString());
 //while debug, prxy.UseDefaultCredentials= false here
//My soap extension gets executed and resets credentials.
prxy.GetEmployee(empId);
```

Comment: This is what I have currently and want to get rid of this... The actual question is how to get rid of this via config.

Comment: Its not possible to get rid of this.